# How to use gettext in Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, gettext

Things run well on my local system.

I want to compile i18l.po on a Django system, which I deployed on heroku. When I run the following command:

```
heroku run python manage.py compilemessages -l en
```

I get an error saying, "CommandError: Can't find msgfmt. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed." Does this mean that there's no gettext module in heroku? Then I tried to install gettext in heroku CLI. Then I install gettext module by running

```
heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/piotras/heroku-buildpack-gettext.git
```

But this fails. So how can I compile translation files in heroku?

---Update---
I managed to run compile command by adding buildpacks on heroku. You can follow tutorials there:[Third-party-buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-third-party-buildpack). But a new issue comes up. Though I compiled .po files successfully, nothing happens.

---Update---
Alright, this issue is also fixed. Because .mo file is ignored by .gitignore. After removing .mo from gitignore file, translation shows up! But I still have another concern about Heroku cycle mechanism, will this .mo files be cleaned up by heroku? I'm using Amazon S3 system for storing static files. But .mo not in any of these folders.